# Setting labels for rowstacked histgram bars

Tags: gnuplot

anybody able to tell me how to add labels to gnuplot rowstacked histogram? I want to add a label to one specific read column.

Data looks like this:

```
Date, Online_Percent, Offline_percent, Maintance_percent
01.01.2013, 96.000, 2.000, 2,000
```

i would like to add another column with "offline_time" and label the bar with it (on top or right into the bar, i don't care about that)

Hope anybody can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a little more clear?  I'm not really sure what you're going for here.  Could you show your script as it is and/or an example of what you're trying to achieve?  It sounds like you just want to plot a single histogram bar with a label on top of it or next to it ...

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but found a solution on an asian site. Solution : '' using 0:($2+50):3 with labels notitle  // 0=x-index ($2+50)=y-index :3=Value from data to be used as label....   Had a hard time to find that piece of infomation XD

Comment: Feel free to post it as a solution and accept it when you're able.  It might be helpful to someone else (who isn't able to find the asian site in a google search ;-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help me, but found a solution on an asian site.

Solution :

```
'' using 0:($2+50):3 with labels notitle 

#Explanation:
0=x-index 
($2+50)=y-index 
3=Value from data to be used as label....
```

You are also able to apply the style settings like this:

```
'' using 0:(\$2-10):2 with labels notitle "'font "1" rotate by -90'
```

Hope it will help others having this question.